# Custom icons with JQuery Mobie using PhoneGap not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile.  I'm trying to use custom button icons.  I have seen many of examples as to how this works but I cannot manage to get it to work within my phone gap app.

In my header I have the following style:

```
                    .ui-icon-customic {
                        background-image: url(/nasa.png);
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    }
                    .ui-icon-customic {
                        background-position: 0 50%;
                    }
```

In the body I have following button:

```
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="customic" data-iconpos="right">Custom Icon</a>
```

A little more background is that style entry is at the last entry in the header after all other JQuery references.

These are the version of the other entries:
phonegap-1.0.0.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css
docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
experiments/themeswitcher/jquery.mobile.themeswitcher.js
docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if your code also should work, here is how I have done it (and it works =) )

```
<a href="#..." id="lang_de_button" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-right">Text</a>
```

Css:

```
#lang_de_button .ui-icon { 
    background: url(images/at.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 11px;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps!